# Why this image is sometimes centered and sometimes not?

Tags: html, css

I didn't change anything in the code.

Sometimes when I load the page the image is centered horizontally and vertically, but sometimes it is centered only horizontally.

***Image is centered:***
[image: screenshot 1]

***Image is not centered:***
[image: screenshot 2]

```
.wavySectionContainer {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: var(--primary);
  position: relative;
}

.aboutMe,
.sun {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

<div class="wavySectionContainer">
    <img class="sun"  src="public/sun.png" alt="Wave">
    <p class="aboutMe">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi officia, mollitia
        cupiditate quae quos voluptatem dolorum? 
        <br><br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: What about alternative options? Why not Grid or Flexbox?

Comment: I went for the absolute position in order to get the text over the image and not side-by-side or in a column. Do you know if I could achieve this with flexbox or grid?

Comment: With Grid, you can put multiple items in the same grid cell. (Can do an answer, but it's late my time so it will be about 12 hours.)

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying by myself in the meantime

Comment: lol, make an example where you can reproduce the bug!

Comment: @DarrylNoakes so what, it's already 12 hours? )) Because it's interesting to look at "Grid or Flexbox"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code uses CSS Grid to place the paragraph atop the image and then centers them using `align-items` and `justify-items`.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.wavySectionContainer {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "content";
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
}

.aboutMe,
.sun {
  grid-area: content;
}
```

```html
<div class="wavySectionContainer">
  <img class="sun" src="https://placekitten.com/200/300" alt="Wave">
  <p class="aboutMe">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi officia, mollitia cupiditate quae quos voluptatem dolorum?
    <br><br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
  </p>
</div>
```

(I do not have your image, so I used PlaceKitten.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will work fine.

```css
.wavySectionContainer {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
}

.aboutMe,
.sun {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wavySectionContainer">
        <img class="sun"  src="https://i.ibb.co/C23WVJ2/pngegg.png" alt="Wave">
        <p class="aboutMe">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi officia, mollitia cupiditate quae quos voluptatem dolorum? <br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
      </div>
```

Comment: _Why_ will it "work fine"? I see you're new here, so I won't push it, but answers should _explain_ the solution. Code-only answers are especially looked down upon.

Comment: I already tried that. Got the same behavior. But thanks anyway

Answer (score -1):

Use height 100vh (viewport height) and width 100vw(viewport width)
OR
use fixed height and width in px(pixels) values, then you will get desired output.

```css
.wavySectionContainer {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
}

.aboutMe,
.sun {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  
}
```

```html
      <div class="wavySectionContainer">
        <img class="sun"  src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/147002/isolated/lists/ebeb92f867932e57e096ebc64a3f884f-abstract-sunshine-rays-icon.png" alt="Wave">
        <p class="aboutMe">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi officia, mollitia cupiditate quae quos voluptatem dolorum? <br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
      </div>
```

Comment: _Don't_ use pixel values for overall sizing.

Comment: Aside from that, this is essentially the same as @ralph.m's answer.

Comment: Same behavior :(